# Accessing activity 2 while foreground is activity 1 (either using OOP or Service in XAMARIN)

Tags: oop, xamarin, service, xamarin.android, location

i code this from a tutorial for locating your location (but I already made some     changes)

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Locations;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Util;
using System.Linq;
using Java.Lang;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Content;

namespace LocatorApp
{

[Activity(Label = "Locator", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/locator_ico")]
public class LocatorApp : Activity, ILocationListener
{
    static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(LocatorApp).Name;
    TextView _addressText;
    Location _currentLocation;
    LocationManager _locationManager;
    Address address;

    string _locationProvider;
    TextView _locationText;
    private double latitude = 0;
    private double longitude = 0;

    public Location getCurrentLocation() { return _currentLocation; }

    public double getLatitude() { return latitude; }

    public double getLongitude() { return longitude; }

    public Address getAddress() { return address; }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        _addressText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.address_text);
        _locationText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.location_text);
        FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.get_address_button).Click += AddressButton_OnClick;

        InitializeLocationManager();
    }

    public void InitializeLocationManager()
    {
        _locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService);
        Criteria criteriaForLocationService = new Criteria
        {
            Accuracy = Accuracy.Coarse,
            PowerRequirement = Power.Medium                
        };

        IList<string> acceptableLocationProviders = _locationManager.GetProviders(criteriaForLocationService, true);

        if (acceptableLocationProviders.Any())
        {
            _locationProvider = acceptableLocationProviders.First();
        }
        else
        {
            _locationProvider = string.Empty;
        }

        Log.Debug(TAG, "Using " + _locationProvider + ".");
    }

    async void AddressButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (_currentLocation == null)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Still waiting for location.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

        else
        {
            try
            {
                var geoUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("geo:" + _currentLocation.Latitude + "," + _currentLocation.Longitude);
                var mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, geoUri);
                StartActivity(mapIntent);
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Sorry, there is a problem with geomapping.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
    }

        async Task<Address> ReverseGeocodeCurrentLocation()
        {
            try
            {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
                IList<Address> addressList =
                await geocoder.GetFromLocationAsync(_currentLocation.Latitude, _currentLocation.Longitude, 10);

                Address address = addressList.FirstOrDefault();
                return address;
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return null;
        }

        void DisplayAddress(Address address)
        {
            if (address != null)
            {
                StringBuilder deviceAddress = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < address.MaxAddressLineIndex; i++)
                {
                    deviceAddress.Append(address.GetAddressLine(i));
                }
                // Remove the last comma from the end of the address.
                _addressText.Text = "Address: "+deviceAddress.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                _addressText.Text = "Unable to determine the address. Try again in a few minutes.";
            }
        }

        public async void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Location changed.", ToastLength.Short).Show();

            _currentLocation = location;
            if (_currentLocation == null)
            {
                _locationText.Text = "Unable to determine your location. Try again in a short while.";
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    _locationText.Text = "Location: " + string.Format("{0:f6},{1:f6}", _currentLocation.Latitude, _currentLocation.Longitude);
                    Address address = await ReverseGeocodeCurrentLocation();
                    DisplayAddress(address);

                    var nMgr = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
                    var notification = new Notification(Resource.Drawable.Icon, "Message from LocatorApp");
                    var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, typeof(LocatorApp)), 0);
                    notification.SetLatestEventInfo(this, "LocatorApp", "Location changed!", pendingIntent);
                    nMgr.Notify(0, notification);
                }
                catch (Java.Lang.Exception e)
                {
                    _addressText.Text = "Unable to determine the address. Try again in a few minutes.";
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Error Occured On Geocoder!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    Log.Error(TAG, e.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider) { }

        public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider) { }

        public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, Availability status, Bundle extras) { }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            if (_locationManager.IsProviderEnabled(_locationProvider))
            {
                _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(_locationProvider, 100, 0, this);
                Toast.MakeText(this, _locationProvider.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "There is a problem with "+_locationProvider.ToString()+" provider.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();
            _locationManager.RemoveUpdates(this);
        }
    }
}
```

(i'm just having my experiment) 
what I want is to run activity **B** while foreground is in activity **A**, just like a basic OOP . but my problem is, I don't know how to make it run. I can't also jump to activity **B** since it has an oncreate method. I instantiated it and can get the variables values but they are null (seems there is no process happened) . What can be a best solution for this.

note: I am currently looking how to use service for background processing but also i don't know how to run this code after I typed it from a tutorial :( there is only a tutorial for creating a service part but no tutorial for buttons to access it :(

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Util;
using System.Threading;

namespace LocatorApp
{
[Service]
class SimpleService : Service
{
    static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(SimpleService).Name;
    static readonly int TimerWait = 4000;
    Timer _timer;

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "OnStartCommand called at {2}, flags={0}, startid={1}", flags, startId, DateTime.UtcNow);
        _timer = new Timer(o => { Log.Debug(TAG, "Hello from SimpleService. {0}", DateTime.UtcNow); },
                           null,
                           0,
                           TimerWait);
        return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();

        _timer.Dispose();
        _timer = null;

        Log.Debug(TAG, "SimpleService destroyed at {0}.", DateTime.UtcNow);
    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        // This example isn't of a bound service, so we just return NULL.
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

I want to know both (OOP way and service way) since not at all time we are required to use the service.

Answer (score 1):

> what I want is to run activity B while foreground is in activity A, just like a basic OOP . but my problem is, I don't know how to make it run. I can't also jump to activity B since it has an oncreate method.

You can call [Context.StartActivity](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Content.Context.StartActivity/) inside your `Activity` with following codes:

```
StartActivity(new Android.Content.Intent(this, typeof(ActivityB)));
```

And `StartActivity` will call `OnCreate` method in ActivityB to create a new instance of ActivityB.

For details about Starting Activities, please refer to [Starting Activities and Getting Results](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.Activity/#Starting_Activities_and_Getting_Results).

> I am currently looking how to use service for background processing but also i don't know how to run this code after I typed it from a tutorial :( there is only a tutorial for creating a service part but no tutorial for buttons to access it :(

Similar like Activity [Context.StartService](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Content.Context.StartService/) offers a way to start a Service:

```
StartService (new Intent (this, typeof(DemoService)));
```

This will call the `OnStartCommand` method inside your Service class.

For details about usage of Service, please refer to [Implementing a Service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/part_1_-_started_services/#Implementing_a_Service).

Comment: thanks for the answer :) although the first answer is not the solution i am looking for and before this solution for question #2 was given, I already solved how to call the service ... still thanks for it ! :) up vote for it . It might help the other searchers to work on :)